# How to make flexbox dimensions force growth of container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox containing elements which have a fixed-width `flex-basis`, and which don't allow growing or shrinking. The elements collectively are wider than the screen width. They display fine, because they're overflow into the `overflow: visible` space of their containers.

But this interacts badly with a `display: sticky` element; I want a sticky element to hover over the flexbox as you scroll.

What I'm seeing is that the sticky element hovers until you scroll one screen-width, and then disappears.

This appears to be because the width of the container with `display: flex` doesn't grow to accommodate its children (and accordingly, neither does the body).

How can I force a container to have its width set to the cumulative width of its flex children?

If I run this javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".container").style.width = document.body.scrollWidth + 'px'
```

(Or equivalently this javascript):

```
document.body.style.width = document.body.scrollWidth + 'px'
```

everything works as I'd like, but ideally I'd like a pure-CSS solution, rather than needing to run javascript to push sizes up to containers.

Example codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjmQRz

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="stickybar">Sticky</div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
}

.stickybar {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.column {
  margin-right: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the container `inline-flex` and use width instead of flex-basis:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 400px;
}

.stickybar {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.column {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="stickybar">Sticky</div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
  </div>
```